# How to install Python3.5.1 in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

I'm having trouble installing python3.5.1 on Ubuntu 20.04, because of libssl-dev version 1.0 being deprecated in ubuntu 20.

How can i workaround this issue to install python3.5.1?

P.S. Need ONLY 3.5.1 version, not 3.5.2, not anything else.

Comment: What's so specific about python 3.5.1

Comment: @AkashKarnatak, I need it to run some of my old projects as I cannot upgrade them easily

Answer (score 0):

Steps to install:

1. Uninstall libssl-dev
2. Install https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-main-amd64/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb.html
3. Install https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-main-amd64/libssl1.0-dev_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb.html
4. pyenv install 3.5.1 or any other ways to compile